# Implementing ArrayList<ContainedObject> where ContainedObject supports getContainningArrayList()

Tags: java, arraylist, extend

I have a class `ContainedObject` which instances are supposed to be contained in an `ArrayList`.

```
public class ContainedObject {
    private ContainerArrayList<ContainedObject> containningArrayList;
    public ContainerArrayList<ContainedObject> getContainningArrayList() {
        return containningArrayList;
    }
    public void setContainningArrayList(ContainerArrayList<ContainedObject> list) {
        containningArrayList = list;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to extend `ArrayList` in such a way that `getContainningArrayList()` of it's contained objects will reflect their "container". For example, I override `add()` this way:

```
public class ContainerArrayList<ContainedObject> extends ArrayList<ContainedObject> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(ContainedObject e) {
        e.setContainningArrayList(this);
        return super.add(e);
    }
}
```

So far so good. The thing is, I want to be able to also call `ContainerArrayList` copy constructor and `clone` methods, etc, and maintain the same containment reflection. So my question is - should I re implement each of these methods, or do they in some way call each other (i.e. `ArrayList(ArrayList)` uses `add` to construct the new arraylist).

Any leads?

Comment: Don't extend ArrayList. Use it. I.e. use composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: @JBNizet: I can see why I rather use composition, to hide `ArrayList`'s unnecessary method (is that what you mean?). 1+ for the idea. But the question remains - if I do want both `add()` and a Copy Constructor for my composed class, do I have to implement both?

Comment: is there a particular reason , you dont want to go for private List<ContainedObject> containningArrayList ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the described behavior you have to override clone method or create a custom constructor (or both) taking Collection as an argument. Using the default methods would make your custom objects point to old *containningArrayList*.

You can see how things work in ArrayList source code:

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    elementData = c.toArray();
    size = elementData.length;
    // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
    if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
}

public Object clone() {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<E> v = (ArrayList<E>) super.clone();
        v.elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
        v.modCount = 0;
        return v;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        // this shouldn't happen, since we are Cloneable
        throw new InternalError();
    }
}
//Arrays.copyOf returns a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with nulls to obtain the specified length
```

Also consider turning ContainedObject to interface.

Comment: Thanks! I feel I now know a little bit more about `ArrayList`'s structure. Of course, looking at the source is the ultimate solution...